# Creating an model (class) that handles everything an MVC View needs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a model that is used by an MVC 4 view and I'm stuck in creating a method that loads values for itself.

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    MyModel _Model = new MyModel();
    _Model.LoadValues(id); //Now that's init'd, get it's values
    return View(_Model);
}
```

The problem is in the method "LoadValues()" - passing "this" as a ref is not allowed =/

MyModel:

```
public class MyModel
{
public string Value1 { get; set; }
public string Value2 { get; set; }

    public MyModel()
    {
    }

    public LoadValues(int id)
    {
        //I would like to pass "this" to the method as a ref so it could directly fill the values
        DAL.LoadMyModel(id, ref this); //doesn't work

        //My work around is this, but there has to be a better way....
        MyModel _TempModel = new MyModel(); //this
        DAL.LoadMyModel(id, ref _TempModel); //is
        Value1 = _TempModel.Value1; //very
        Value2 = _TempModel.Value2; //terribad
    }

}
```

I guess I could also change the "LoadValues(int id)" to "LoadValues(int id, ref MyModel _TempModel)", and if that's the right way of doing it I guess that's what I'll do.  But it'd be so nice to pass in "this" !! :)

Is what i'm trying to do possible?  why is "this" readonly and can't be passed to another method?

Comment: Try to remove ref. Values will be filled directly without ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd only need `ref` in this case if you want to change the instance that the reference is pointing to, so passing `ref this` is illegal becauce you can't change what `this` is pointing to.

You can remove the `ref` keyword on the call (and the `LoadMyModel` definition) and the DAL will (presumably) fill out the properties of the "`this"` instance.

*Personally*, I prefer to have the DAL *return* instances rather than *filling* them, so I would do something like this in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    MyModel _Model = DAL.LoadMyModel(id); 
    return View(_Model);
}
```

and inject the `DAL` class to the model so I'm not bound to a particular `DAL`.  As it stands you *seem* to be binding the model to the DAL which may come back to bite you later.

Comment: Although Phil answered first, your explanation is easier to understand.  As for your preference of using the DAL to init, I agree, in fact that's how I had it originally, but what i'm experimenting with (and liking) is having all the methods in the model and keeping the controller dumb.  So on a load, I can simply call "View(new MyModel(id));" and on the postback "_Model.Save()".  In the end, the code runs the same - so it's really a preference and maintainability decision, I suppose.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Although Me answered first in comment... xD

Comment: You're right Vladmirs!! If I could give you and Phil some points I would =/  But Stanley still gave a little better explanation :)
Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use "ref".  Your MyModel class is a reference type, so will always be passed by reference.

Comment: Technically you're passing a _reference_ by _value_, but your solution is correct.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think about passing it without the "ref" keyword. Doh.  Trying it now.